# Unable to load dynamic library (dyld: Library not loaded: libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib)

Tags: macos, makefile, cmake, intel, intel-mkl

I experience the following problem running a Fortran code compiled with Intel Fortran compiler (15.0.3) and Intel MKL on macOS Sierra 10.12.3:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/tst_ddot/bin/./tst_ddot
  Reason: image not found
Command terminated by signal 6
```

To compile the code I use `cmake` (3.7.2) and to run the code `make` (GNU 3.81, built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0).

The source code:

```
  PROGRAM tst_xdot

  USE OMP_LIB

  IMPLICIT NONE

  integer, parameter :: N = 10
  integer :: err
  real, allocatable  :: a(:), b(:)
  real :: c1, c2
  real :: t0, t1, time

  real, external :: sdot


  allocate(a(N), b(N), stat=err)

  a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  b = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

  c1 = 0.0d+0
  c2 = 0.0d+0

  print *, "a:", a
  print *, "b:", b

  c1 = dot_product(a, b)

  t0   = omp_get_wtime()
  c2   = sdot(N, a, 1, b, 1)
  t1   = omp_get_wtime()
  time = t1-t0

  print *, "c1:",   c1
  print *, "c2:",   c2
  print *, "time:", time

  deallocate(a, b, stat=err)

  END PROGRAM tst_xdot
```

`CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
# Minimum cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5)

# Project name
project(tst_ddot Fortran)

# set binary directory
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../bin)

# Toolchain selection, possible arguments: Intel
set(Toolchain Intel)

# Intel compilers
if (${Toolchain} MATCHES Intel)
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-O3 ${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}")
endif (${Toolchain} MATCHES Intel)

# Enable MKL library
include_directories($ENV{MKLROOT}/include)
link_directories($ENV{MKLROOT}/lib)

# Enable OpenMP
find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_Fortran_FLAGS}")
endif()

# Source code files
set(SRC tst_ddot.f90)

# Main executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS} mkl_intel_lp64 mkl_intel_thread mkl_core pthread m)
```

The problem only appears when I run the code using a make file:

```
make run
```

Make file to control the program execution:

```
CODE = tst_ddot

run:
    ./$(CODE)
```

If I run the code directly from the command line as:

```
./tst_ddot
```

The program executes normally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by using a newer version of the GNU `make` (GNU Make 4.2.1, built for x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0). In case of MacPorts it will be called `gmake` and installed into `/opt/local/bin/gmake` by default. Therefore, the correct command to run the code should be:

```
gmake run
```